# android Extra_Steam

Tags: android, android-intent

i made an int array with my drawables in it

```
_imageResources = new int[] {R.drawable.p001, R.drawable.p002, R.drawable.p003, R.drawable.p004, R.drawable.p005, R.drawable.p006, R.drawable.p007, R.drawable.p008, R.drawable.p009,
           R.drawable.p010, R.drawable.p011, R.drawable.p012, R.drawable.p013, R.drawable.p014, R.drawable.p015, R.drawable.p016, R.drawable.p017, R.drawable.p018, R.drawable.p019,
           R.drawable.p020, R.drawable.p021, R.drawable.p022, R.drawable.p023, R.drawable.p024, R.drawable.p025, R.drawable.p026, R.drawable.p027, R.drawable.p028, R.drawable.p029, };
```

i use this to get the image

```
public int GetCurrentImage() {
  return _imageResources[_currentImageIndex];
 }
```

and display it using this

```
 _imageview.setBackgroundResource(GetCurrentImage());
```

now i need to figure out a way to attach the currently displayed image to my ACTION_SEND intent
the code is

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(jpg));
```

but i have absolutely no idea how i would get a Uri from my code for the image, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to copy your drawable contents to a file which would be accessible by outer world applications, i.e. on SD card. The use the file to create an Uri string.